# DCGAN celebA strange results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to generate attributed faces using DCGAN. Therefore I changed the code of the original implementation to use celebA instead of mnist. After 15 iterations I am getting the following results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrbb.png

Here can you find my [modifications](https://github.com/hpobaschnig/DCGAN-conditional-celebA) to the original DCGAN implementation:

1) Read the celebA attributes

```
  self.celeba_labels = []
  with open("./list_attr_celeba.txt") as celeba_labels_list:
   #Skip header
   next(celeba_labels_list)
   next(celeba_labels_list)
   for celeba_label_line in celeba_labels_list:
       #Prepare label list
       image_label = celeba_label_line.split()
       image_label = image_label[1:]
       image_label = map(int, image_label)
       image_label = [0 if label == -1 else 1 for label in image_label]

       self.celeba_labels.append(image_label)
```

2) Use them as sample labels (like mnist)

```
sample_labels = self.celeba_labels[0:self.sample_num]
```

3) Use them as batch labels (like mnist)

```
batch_labels = self.celeba_labels[idx*config.batch_size: (idx+1)*config.batch_size]
```

Why isn't the network producing faces as results?